# How to attach debugger to app if it has protection against attaching?

Tags: anti-debugging

Sometimes I've tried to attach Ollydbg to applications those have some protection against debuggers, but I have never coded any of these applications and did not see this protection in many applications... So it looks like it is not hard to bypass this, however I am curious and never tried it before. How do you do it guys? (at least some examples on some simple program).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of anti-debug protection are you refering to ? Testing `ptrace` can only be done with a test which will be localized in the code. And, I am not sure that attaching to a running software will cause a `0xcc` to be written (does it?). So, self-check routine to detect modification of the source code will fail as wel.. My guess is that you just need to be lucky when you attach you debugger to the program and to stop it in a safe mode.

Comment: Completely platform dependent. On windows, a common trick is to patch certain routines (in ntdll) that are invoked by the kernel as soon as the debugger is attached. A solution to this is to simply restore ntdll in memory right before attaching. I think this question is pretty borad, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anti-attaching depends heavily on the fact that windows creates a remote thread in the target
process. What is specific about this thread is usually used to detect attaching.

For example: 
The entry point Windows chooses for the attaching thread is by default the "DbgUiRemoteBreakin" function. Anti-attaching tricks usually hook this function or its
sibling, the "DbgBreakPoint" function.

Also, The fact that the attaching thread (like most normal threads) will have
the associated TLS callbacks called is also exploited to detect attaching.

Debug blocks, NtContinue, ThreadHideFromDebugger etc.

http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2011/12/debuggers-anti-attaching-techniques.html
http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2011/12/debuggers-anti-attaching-techniques_11.html
http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2011/12/debuggers-anti-attaching-techniques_13.html
http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2012/02/debuggers-anti-attaching-techniques_15.html
http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2012/11/sizeofstackreserve-as-anti-attaching.html