# Attaching debugger to process IDA Pro privilege problem

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk, process, error-messages

I am trying to attach the WinDBG to particular process but I constantly get the error below :
[image] 
I am using win 7 x64 and am trying to debug x64 application.
I run the IDA Pro with admin privileges. I have run the application both with admin privilege and the user one. I even tried to run it on different windows user account with admin privilege but I still get the same error.

Comment: The target process may have anti-attach protection. See *[this](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/how-to-attach-debugger-to-app-if-it-has-protection-against-attaching)* post.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders The problem is I can easily attach to the process in x64_DBG. This issue occurs only in IDA Pro

Comment: Are you using IDA x64?

Comment: @AcidShout Yes I am using IDA x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot debug a 64 bit application locally with IDA Pro. 

You need to use remote debugging.

See this page: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/#details

and this: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/cross-win-linux/win32towin64.shtml

Comment: I am win7 x64 - Should I run the IDA on VMware x86 OS and then make remote debugging on my x64 application through VMware? What would the scenario for my situation?

Comment: @FreeMind You can copy the debugging server  `win64_remotex64.exe` to the target machine(x64). Now in the other VM(32/64), run IDA 64, and use `attach to remote win64` to debug.

Comment: Where is `win64_remotex64.exe` located at? I have checked `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64` but there is no file over there.

Comment: @FreeMind `win64_remotex64.exe` is a part of IDA. Check within your IDA installation directory.